# difference between InstancedMesh and Object3D.clone() in three.js

Tags: three.js

i've been learning how to improve the performance of my 3d apps, i've been told that i can use Object3D.clone() to duplicate identical objects, and i can use InstancedMesh when rendering numbers of objects with same geometry and material to improve performance. Could someone please tell me what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object3D.clone()` means each cloned 3D object is rendered with an individual draw call. However, this approach might downgrade the performance of your app since the number of draw calls is an an important performance metric of 3D applications. It should be as low as possible.

Using `InstancedMesh` can help to decrease the number of draw calls since all its instances are render with a single draw call.

So instead of cloning objects, you should use instanced rendering whenever possible.